# React: best practices of mixing controlled components and uncontrolled components in one multi-step form

Tags: reactjs, forms

Using the pattern of `controlled components` in react to make a complex form is easy and straight-forward.

However, things can become quite tricky when we have one field in the form that is an **uncontrolled component**. (e.g. a very complex legacy system component that was built with jQuery)

The uncontrolled component does not know about `value` and `onChange`, and its only API is `setData` and `getData`.

What's worse, this component may be placed on the second step of a multi-step form, or it may only show when a certain option is selected. That is to say, this component can mount and unmount quite unpredictably, its `ref` often not available.

What are some of the good practices to deal with this problem? How can we write predictable, elegant and maintainable code that integrates both controlled components and uncontrolled components?

Answer (score 2):

One way that I can think of is to wrap the uncontrolled component with an HOC, which reads data from `props.value` and calls `setData` in `componentDidMount`, and calls `getData` and `props.onChange` in `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: this is correct, but suggest using functional component,